# Can't make a simple HelloWorld jetty webapp

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to deploy a simple Helloworld webapp in my jetty v9.1. I am having problems when i am trying to access the servlet, I recive an error message:

HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /HelloServlet/servlet. Reason:

```
Not Found
```

I know i am doing something wrong here but i can't tell what.

here is my file structure from Webbapp in jetty:

> webapps
>
> > +example
> >
> > > +hello
> > >
> > > > hello.xml
> > > >         index.html
> > > >         +WEB-INF
> > > >
> > > > > web.xml
> > > > >           +classes
> > > > >
> > > > > > HelloServlet.class

index.html +WEB-INF (reprezent a folder,WEB-INF and a file index.html, in same folder hello)

**here is my web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
version="2.5">
<display-name>Example</display-name>

<!-- Declaraa existenta unui servlet. -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>HelloServlet</servlet-class>

</servlet>

<!-- Map URLs to that servlet. -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

---

HelloServlet.java

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

   String input=request.getParameter("input");
   PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

   out.println("<html>");
   out.println("<body>");
   out.println("The parameter input was \" "+input+"\" .");
   out.println("</body");
   out.println("</html");

}


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    String field=request.getParameter("field");
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("You entered \" "+field+"\" into the text box.");
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");

}

}
```

---

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Web Application</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>This is a static document with a form in it.</p>
    <form method="POST" action="servlet">
        <input name="field" type="text" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**hello.xml**

```
<<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">



<<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
<Set name="contextPath">/hello</Set>
<Set name="extractWAR">false</Set>
<Set name="copyWebDir">false</Set>
<Set name="defaultsDescriptor"><Property name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/webdefault.xml</Set>
<Call name="setAttribute">
<Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356</Arg>
<Arg type="Boolean">true</Arg>
</Call>

<Get name="securityHandler">
<Set name="loginService">
  <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
    <Set name="name">Test Realm</Set>
    <Set name="config"><SystemProperty name="jetty.base" default="."/>/etc/realm.properties</Set>
  </New>
</Set>
<Set name="authenticator">
  <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.FormAuthenticator">
    <Set name="alwaysSaveUri">true</Set>
  </New>
</Set>
<Set name="checkWelcomeFiles">true</Set>
</Get>

</Configure>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution after all and my problem is fixed. I just started the server from Intellij Idea and everything works perfectly.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 3):

In your `web.xml`, you specified the `url-pattern` as `/servlet/*`, meaning that the prefix you need to use is `servlet/`, not `HelloServlet/`:

```
http://localhost:8080/servlet/servlet
```

(And while it can be instructional to write a servlet by hand, for real-world projects it's better to go with a system like Spring that already has all of the plumbing taken care of for you.)

Comment: yes you are probaly right about Spring, but i have to use this style for the moment so i can learn about servlet and jetty, i am new at this, so sory about the dumb questions. I also tried your suggestion but I still get the same error, I even try to make url-pattern as /servlet and use prefix as servlet

Comment: @AdrianTotolici Like I said, it's good to know how the things work at a low level. I'm not sure what you are saying you did differently. Please post the entire URL you're trying to load.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/servlet ,and i also edited the new modification in url in my question above

Comment: @AdrianTotolici How are you launching your application? Do you have a `war` file? What is it called?

Comment: I've added a new xml file in my question, and no don't use a war file i want to use file sitem already decompresed. I lunch the application by starting jetty server in comand line like 'java -jar start.jar'